# Weak topology on unit ball

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I have the following problem:
$X \in \mathbb{K}$ linear space and $F,f_1,\ldots,f_n : X \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ linear with

$$ \bigcap_{i=1}^n N (f_i) \subset N (F)$$

Show that $F$ is a linear combination of $f_i$.

Maybe it works with induction but I have no clue how to start.

This should help me to solve then why $B^\circ _1 (0) = (x \in X : ||x||_x <1)$ (unit ball) is empty for weak topology on $X$ with $(X,||.||_x)$ being an infinite dimensional normed space.

Can someone help me to show that? especially with the linear combination?

Comment: This has nothing to do with topology whatsoever. It is a purely algebraic property of linear forms.

Comment: Are the $f_n$ finite in number?

Comment: @copper.hat yes they are finite.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro my main question has nothing to do with it but after that i need to show that the unit ball is empty in weak topology.

Comment: You should replace the $\infty$ by $n$.

Comment: "empty for weak topology" is meaningless.

Comment: Ah,  I missed a detail in the notation. Writing $B^\circ = (x \in X | ||x|| <1)$ is wrong. _What does the problem actually ask_?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Its $B^\circ _1 (0) = (x \in X | ||x||_x <1)$. I guess its my bad english causing problems. it literally says the inner of the unit ball is empty regarding/for weak topology on X. One result of this is that the unit ball is not open in weak topology (but norm topology)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\K}{\mathbb K}$

As stated the problem really doesn't make sense. I'm going to assume you meant to write $$\bigcap_{i=1}^nN(f_i)\subset N(F).$$

Define $T:X\to\K^n$ by $$Tx=(f_1x,\dots,f_nx).$$

Let $Y=T(X)$, the image of $Y$ under $T$. Attempt to define $L:Y\to\K$ by $$L(Tx)=F(x)\quad(x\in X).$$

That defines a linear map from $Y$ to $\K$ *if* it is well-defined. That is, we need to show that

> > If $Tx=Tx'$ then $Fx=Fx'$.

But this is clear: If $Tx=Tx'$ then $x-x'\in N(f_j)$ for every $j$, hence $x-x'\in N(F)$, so $Fx=Fx'$.

So $L:Y\to\K$ is linear. We can *extend* $L$ to a linear map $L:\K^n\to\K$. (If this is not clear, start with a basis $B$ for $Y$. Since $B$ is an independent subset of $\K^n$ there exists a basis $B'$ for $\K^n$ with $B\subset B'$. Now extend $L$ from $Y$ to $\K^n$ by declaring $Lb=0$ for every $b\in B'\setminus B$.)

Now since $L$ is a linear functional on $\K^n$ there exist $c_1,\dots,c_n\in\K$ such that $$Lk=c_1k_1+\dots c_nk_n\quad(k\in\K^n).$$

Hence if $x\in X$ then $$Fx=L(Tx)=c_1f_1(x)+\dots+c_nf_nx.$$

**Edit** Note the result is false for infinitely many $f_j$. for example let $X=\ell_1$, $f_jx=x_j$, $Fx=\sum_{j=1}^\infty x_j$.

Comment: I apologize for the bad phrasing. That is exactly what i meant. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SquareJoe You should edit the question to correct it! Also you might "accept" my answer - click on the little check mark...

Comment: I will. i just try to figure out how to apply this to find out why the unit ball is empty (inner) first

Comment: @SquareJoe This is absurd. You just edited the question but you did't fix the error.

Comment: @SquareJoe You really really really need to be more precise or you don't have a chance. So far you stated what you want to prove about the unit ball three times - only one of those statements was correct! You can't prove the unit  ball is empty because it's not. Saying "the unit ball is empty(inner)" makes no sense.

Comment: You are right. $(X, ||.||)$ be a infinite dimensional normed space. I want to show that $B=(x \in X |  ∥x∥ < 1)$ is empty regarding the weak topology for X

Comment: Aargh. There's no such thing as "empty regarding a topology". What do you actually want to show?